# Proper way to use directory as argument of batch script in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, batch-file

I am trying to pass a directory as an argument to a batch script in vb.net. Below is the action from a button. What is the proper way of using a directory name as an argument (or two directory names in this case)? Currently, I have hard-coded test directories in an attempt to debug, but the result is not as expected. Rather than using the directory as an input, it seems to ignore it. This seems like a string issue or something of the sorts. Please forgive my terrible code; I am still in my infancy with vb.

The .bat file takes two arguments (the first being an input folder, and the second being an output folder/location), then launches an analysis of each dataset within the input folder. I will eventually take user input, defined by a browse button, and use it as input/output locations. The .bat file works perfectly in cmd and powershell via the following:

```
.\Scripts\census_splitter.bat C:\Users\Foo\Documents\Census_Splitter\Data\ C:\Users\Foo\Documents\Census_Splitter\Output\
```

The problem seems to arise when it is moved over to vb.net.

```
Private Sub RunButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RunButton.Click
        'Declare Variables'
        Dim census_splitter As String = IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "Census_Splitter\Scripts\census_splitter.bat")
            
        'Batch Script'
        Dim p As New Process
        Process.Start(census_splitter).WaitForExit()
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor
        Application.DoEvents()
        p.StartInfo.FileName = census_splitter
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = "C:\Users\Foo\Documents\Census_Splitter\Data\" & " " & "C:\Users\Foo\Documents\Census_Splitter\Output\"
        p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
        p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
        p.Start()
        p.WaitForExit()
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default



    End Sub
```

Any ideas would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Firstly, concatenating literal `Strings` is nuts. It won't inherently hurt but but it serves no useful purpose and it makes your code harder to read why `"C:\Users\Foo\Documents\Census_Splitter\Data\" & " " & "C:\Users\Foo\Documents\Census_Splitter\Output\"` when you can use `"C:\Users\Foo\Documents\Census_Splitter\Data\ C:\Users\Foo\Documents\Census_Splitter\Output\"`?

Comment: As for the issue, the only thing that I can see that I think might be an issue is that you're not setting the `WorkingDirectory` for the process. That would only matter if the batch file relies on that though. Does the batch file assume a specific working directory when looking for some other file?

Comment: Execute `cmd.exe` with arguments `$"/K census_splitter.bat ""{path1}"" ""{path2}"""`. You can also use `/C` when you see it's ok. Set `UseShellExecute = false`.

Comment: Is this a .NET Core or .NET Framework application? I'm not sure that it should make a difference but you're not setting `UseShellExecute` and they default to different values for that.

Comment: See also the `/C START /b /WAIT` option.